# Connecting a sump pump to a 4" drain

Tags: pump, backyard, sump

I am installing a sump pump in my backyard. There already is a 4” PVC drain pipe that runs approximately 120’ to the street and has a 1% downhill slope.

Can the 1 1/2” to 2” outlet pipe from the sump pump be connected to the 4” PVC drain pipe?

Comment: Yes.  Small to bigger is good.  Big to small is bad.

Comment: Also depends what that drain pipe is for.  Some places do not like people connecting sump pumps to a sewer line.

Comment: If it's draining to street, it is probably fine -- but do check local rules